# Programmatically turn off an individual monitor

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there an API or way to programmatically turn off an individual, external monitor via Objective-C on a Mac?

I'm looking to write a small menubar application that can control a secondary display (without a physical power button), but still keep the primary monitor in use.

Hunting around the API documentation, I can't seem to find anything, other then reading states. So hoping someone else might have an idea.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be possible to sleep display so by [I/O Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html):

- https://web.archive.org/web/20161106204726/http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/191807-sleep-display.html
- http://explanatorygap.net/2009/01/31/a-screensaver-to-send-your-display-to-sleep/

But I am not sure whether it can control single monitors.

Comment: I saw this, but the issue is it's to put the display to sleep, and not power it down. Meaning (as I would hope), as-soon as you start to use the machine with only 1 monitor on wouldn't the asleep monitor just wake itself automatically up?

Comment: I am not familiar with Quartz Display Services but did you check whether it has the ability to do what you want? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Looks like Quartz services will only allow return values to be read of current states.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "programmatically turn off an individual monitor", it's not physically possible. The most you can do is tell the OS to not use the monitor, but I don't think you can change system-wide settings like that, especially not at the level you're working on (Obj-C).

Looking at the Core Graphics API mentioned in @Halley's comment, try starting with the [`CGBeginDisplayConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001070-CH202-CGBeginDisplayConfiguration) method and see if you can set a display configuration to your liking.

*EDIT:* Alternatively, you could also use [`CGDisplayCapture`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001070-CH202-F17097)`(displayID)`, which by default fills the captured display with black. You can then
call [`CGDisplayRelease`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001070-CH202-F17105)`(displayID)` when you want to turn it back on.